# Display suddenly blacked out

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have this rig in my lab that i use for Virtualisation and Gaming.Something strange happened yesterday while i was using it.The Dual monitors i am running suddenly blacked out i had to press the reset button.Monitors went off but the computer was running and am puzzled.I have reset the Motherboard to its defaults and disabled overclocking.But i need to know what could have caused this.I have recently installed an AMD Radeon HD 6950 and a cooler master 500w smps.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware problem, but it could really be anything. The first thing I'd look at would be the PSU - I've had experiences in the past where if the voltage on a particular line fluctuates or drops too much, a similar thing happens.

First thing I'd do is put the original components back in to see if is stable. Then change one thing at a time to see if you can isolate what's causing the problem. Then I'd plug a voltmeter into a molex plug to monitor voltages. If they look to be constantly within tolerence (+/- 5%) then I'd move onto looking at the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a newly upgraded system, I would suspect **overheating** to be the problem.  Running a fan speed/temperature logging application may point out an overheating issue.  If so, it's likely that you installed the heat-sink or fans improperly.

Alternately, your overclocking settings may be a bit too aggressive which could show up under heavy load such as gaming.  Dial them back slightly until the machine becomes stable.